# Can a parameter be used in a PreAuthorize annotation which is diffrent from the annotation's marked method parameter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, annotations

In our spring boot application I am trying to implement a custom annotation `@HasRight("admin")` which uses the @PreAuthorize annotation. Inside this annotation I want to call a service which will then check the rights.

My problem is, if I use an other name for the parameter than in the finally "secured" method the value of my parameter inside my service is always null.

For example the method I'am trying to secure:

```
@HasRight("admin")
@GetMapping({"", "/{foo}})
public Response getOptions(@PathVariable(required = false) String foo) {
    // Do something with foo
    ...
    return Response;
}
```

The interface looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("@myService.hasRight(#value)")
public @interface HasRight {
    String value();
}
```

The method is called every time, but the value is always null.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    public final boolean hasRight(String value) {
        // value is null here!
        ...
    }
}
```

Except I would change the name of the parameter on the HasRight interface to foo (and #foo). But then the parameter is set according to the parameter which is passed to the getOptions method. But I want to use a different name, because these values are independent and I want to set it in my annotation obviously.

Is this even possible with `@PreAuthorize` or do I have to consider using `@Aspect`?

Comment: You need an `@AliasFor` on the `value()` to indicate it is a alias for the value attribute on the `@PreAuthorize`. Also the `#value` (or other expression) is, as you noticed, for accessing the method argument with that name.

Comment: This did not work, it was still null. Is it even possible with `#var` to access the argument passed inside the annotation e.g. @HasRight("admin") or is it only for accessing the method arguments?

Comment: It is the latter it only access the method arguments and not the annotations, it is a SpEL expression so the annotation metadata isn't really available. I don't think it is possible to pass the annotation to the expression to obtain the metadata from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming)

The interface:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface HasRight {
    String value();
}
```

The aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class HasRightAspect {

    private final RightService rightService;

    public HasRightAspect(RightService rightService) {
        this.RightService = rightService;
    }

    @Before("@within(hasRight)")
    public void checkClassAnnotation(HasRight hasRight) {
        this.checkRights(hasRight);
    }

    @Before("@annotation(hasRight)")
    public void checkMethodAnnotation(HasRight hasRight) {
        this.checkRights(hasRight);
    }

    private void checkRights(HasRight hasRight) {
        String right = hasRight.value();
        if (!this.rightService.hasRights(right)) {
            throw new NotEnoughRightsException(right);
        }
    }
}
```

| Element | Verwendung |
| --- | --- |
| @Before | Advice that executes before a join point, but which does not have the ability to prevent execution flow proceeding to the join point (unless it throws an exception). |
| @within | Any join point (method execution only in Spring AOP) where the declared type of the target object has an specific annotation. |
| @annotation | Any join point (method execution only in Spring AOP) where the executing method has an specific annotation. |

Information from [11. Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)